# product of the terms of two series that diverges to $\infty$

Tags: analysis, divergent-series

Suppose that $0\leq p_n\leq 1$ for each $n$. Also suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n = \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p_{n}) = \infty$. How can you prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n (1 - p_{n+1}) = \infty$?

Comment: Are there other hypothesis? Because $p_n = 0$ if $n$ is even and $p_n = 1$ if $n$ is odd, would satisfy the hypothesis, but the series of the products would be equal to $0$

Comment: Does that make more sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that $0\le p_n\le 1$ for all $n$. If you want to solve this problem without that assumption, this solution won't work.

Split into three cases:

1. $p_n\ge\frac12$ from some point $n_0$ onward. Then $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty p_n(1-p_{n+1}) \ge \frac12 \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty (1-p_{n+1}) = \infty$.
2. $p_n\le\frac12$ from some point $n_0$ onward. Then $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty p_n(1-p_{n+1}) \ge \frac12 \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty p_n = \infty$.
3. Neither of the above hold. Then there are infinitely many $n_j$ such that $p_{n_j} \ge \frac12$ and $p_{n_j+1} \le \frac12$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n(1-p_{n+1}) \ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty p_{n_j}(1-p_{n_j+1}) \ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac14 = \infty$.

Comment: And I note that the claim is false without some further assumption like positivity, as the counterexample $\{p_n\} = \{2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,2,2,2,-1,-1,-1,\dots\}$ shows.

Comment: Yeah, $0 \leq p_n \leq 1$ must hold. Thanks.